# Application().connect in PyWinAuto Cannot Find the Element I want

Tags: python, selenium, pywinauto

I am using Selenium& Chrome Webdriver and I need to upload a Image file.
Since I cannot send the file using SendKeys, I am tring to handle the windows File Browser using PyWinAuto.

So  after I click the find file button using selenium, I have to use PyWinAuto to find the windows file browser that has been opened, So I have used `Applications().connect`.

This is the code I need help with.

```
app=Application().connect(title_re="Open")
app.FileUpload.Edit.SetText("screenshot.png")
time.sleep(5)
app.FileUpload.Button.click()
```

The Error comes on the first row of the code, Which says

> ElementNotFoundError: {'title_re': 'Open', 'backend': 'win32', 'visible_only': False}

I do not understand why the Element Cannot be found.
I upload a picture of the windows File browser I need to find.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Application(), use Desktop() as shown below.
print_control_identifiers() will print identifiers for controls and its descendants. You can use appropriate control from the output to upload your file.

```
from pywinauto import Desktop
app=Desktop().window(title="Open")
app.print_control_identifiers()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are getting, looks like it's because it cannot find an application with the title of "Open". In your screenshot, it still looks like that's a Chrome window rather than a Window Explorer window.

The best way to know, is to use a tool to find different elements, a great one is 'inspect.exe' that comes standard on windows. Instructions on how to find this are [here](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#gui-objects-inspection-spy-tools).

I've also found that sometimes, it's needed to use Desktop() rather than Application().

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using uiautomation:

```
import uiautomation
path = uiautomation.EditControl(Name = "File name:")
path.SetFocus()
path.SendKeys(file_path)
btn = uiautomation.ButtonControl(Name = "Open")
btn.SetFocus()
btn.Invoke()
fil = uiautomation.EditControl(Name="File name:")
fil.SetFocus()
fil.SendKeys(file_name + '{Enter}')
```

You can use SendKeys(file_path + file_name + '{Enter}'), but in python the '\' is not dectected as a string, so I have to split them into 2 part.

Answer (score 0):

With uiautomation, it works good for me, Here is the code

```
path = uiautomation.EditControl(Name = "File name:")
path.SetFocus()
path.SendKeys(file) #file=filepath
btn = uiautomation.ButtonControl(Name = "Open")
btn.SetFocus()
fil = uiautomation.EditControl(Name="File name:")
fil.SetFocus()
fil.SendKeys('{Enter}')
```